# React uses a single thread when processing a channel

Tags: concurrency, raku

My intention is to have different threads reading simultaneously from a single channel, and processing things asynchronously. I thought this would do the trick:

```
my Channel $KXGA .= new;

for ^100 {
    $KXGA.send( (100000..200000).pick );
}

my $sums = start react whenever $KXGA -> $number {
    say "In thread ", $*THREAD.id;
    say "→ ", (^$number).sum;
}
```

(this hangs up because I'm not closing the channel, but please don't look at that). This outputs, whatever I do:

```
In thread 4
→ 6995966328
In thread 4
→ 12323793510
In thread 4
→ 5473561506
```

So it's always using a single thread and processing things sequentially, and not in parallel. Is there some way of doing that? Even if I `start` the thread within the `whenever` block, the result will be exactly the same...

Comment: One of the features of `react` is that only one thread can be in it at a time.

Comment: Yep, but theoretically, it's only there when it's reading from it, and it's a quick read...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `react`/`whenever` construct is intended for processing one message at a time and in full. The point is that state held within the `react` block is safe thanks to this.

It's possible to have multiple workers reading from a `Channel`; they'll just need setting up as follows:

```
my @sums;
for ^4 {
    push @sums, start react whenever $KXGA -> $number {
        say "In thread ", $*THREAD.id;
        say "→ ", (^$number).sum;
    }
}
```

This `react` approach, when used with `use v6.d.PREVIEW`, has the advantage that when there's less work, it won't actually occupy 4 threads at all, and they can get on with other pooled work. If instead the whole application is just processing stuff from the `Channel` and that's all, you'll have less overhead and better locality with just:

```
my @sums;
for ^4 {
    push @sums, start for $KXGA.list -> $number {
        say "In thread ", $*THREAD.id;
        say "→ ", (^$number).sum;
    }
}
```

Unlike with `react` there's no opportunity to react to different data sources in this approach (the reason `Channel`s work with `react` is primarily so you can consume them and simultaneously work with async data sources too, or perhaps deal with multiple channels at once). But if you don't need to, then the `for` way is a tad simpler in the code and is almost certainly faster (and, as with `react`, the loops compete over the items in the `Channel` and terminate gracefully when it is closed).